# How to get Font weight in C#?

Tags: c#, fonts

I am trying to get the font weight of a font however this seems to require some sort of voodoo magic in C#.

I found and converted this enum to help figure it out, and I use FontDialog to choose the Font.

```
    public enum FontWeight
    {
        Black = 900,
        UltraBold = 800,
        DemiBold = 600,
        Regular = 400,
        UltraLight = 200,
        Heavy = 900,
        ExtraBold = 800,
        Bold = 700,
        SemiBold = 600,
        Medium = 500,
        ExtraLight = 200,
        Thin = 100,
        DoNotCare = 0,
        Normal = 400,
        Light = 300
    }
```

However even though the FontDialog allows me to choose some of the corresponding font styles the font returned by the FontDialog only contains styles contained in the C# enum of FontStyle(Bold, Italic, Regular, Strikeout, Underline).

For example if I choose a font that has the Light style the returned Font will only have the Regular style.

Is there any way of getting font weight in C#? I don't intend to use the font in the program itself I just need to figure out the weight for another program.

Comment: i think you need to write your own Font Class that inherit from actual font class with your own parameters that accept your enum "font weight" and then convert it to font size and pass it on to font base class. my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with, doesn't include designer code. Sorry if I offend anyone with this noob code. This uses GlypTypeface class from System.Windows.Media to get most of the information and LogFont to get the height.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Media;


public partial class FontPicker : Form
{
    public Result ChoosenFont = new Result();

    private Dictionary<string, List<GlyphTypeface>> FontCollection = new Dictionary<string, List<GlyphTypeface>>();

    int[] sizes = new int[] { 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 36, 48, 72 };

    public class Result
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Height;
        public string Weight;
    }


    public FontPicker(string currentFont)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        foreach (int i in sizes)
        {
            listBoxSize.Items.Add(i);
        }

        int index = listBoxSize.FindStringExact("8");
        listBoxSize.SelectedIndex = index;

        var fontFilesPersonal = GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + @"\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts", new string[] { "*.ttf", "*.otf" }, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        var fontFilesWindows = GetFiles(@"C:\Windows\Fonts", new string[] { "*.ttf", "*.otf" }, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

        List<string> fontFiles = new List<string>();

        fontFiles.AddRange(fontFilesWindows);
        fontFiles.AddRange(fontFilesPersonal);

        foreach (string fontFile in fontFiles)
        {
            GlyphTypeface ttf = new GlyphTypeface(new Uri(fontFile));

            string name = ttf.Win32FamilyNames.First().Value;

            if (!FontCollection.ContainsKey(name))
            {
                FontCollection.Add(name, new List<GlyphTypeface>());
            }

            FontCollection[name].Add(ttf);
        }

        var fonts = FontCollection.Keys.ToList();

        fonts.Sort();

        foreach (string name in fonts)
        {
            listBoxFonts.Items.Add(name);
        }

        index = listBoxFonts.FindStringExact(currentFont);
        if (index != -1) { listBoxFonts.SelectedIndex = index; }
        else
        {
            index = listBoxFonts.FindStringExact("Unispace");
            if (index != -1) { listBoxFonts.SelectedIndex = index; }
            else
            {
                index = listBoxFonts.FindStringExact("Arial");
                listBoxFonts.SelectedIndex = index;
            }

        }

    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string path,
                   string[] searchPatterns,
                   SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    {
        return searchPatterns.AsParallel()
               .SelectMany(searchPattern =>
                      Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, searchPattern, searchOption));
    }

    private void buttonAccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FontWeight weight = (FontWeight)listBoxStyle.SelectedItem;
        string fontName = listBoxFonts.SelectedItem as string;
        int size = (int)listBoxSize.SelectedItem;

        LOGFONT logFont = new LOGFONT();

        Font lfont = (new Font(fontName, size, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular));
        lfont.ToLogFont(logFont);

        ChoosenFont.Weight = weight.ToOpenTypeWeight().ToString();
        ChoosenFont.Name = fontName;
        ChoosenFont.Height = logFont.lfHeight.ToString();

        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        Close();
    }

    private void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        Close();
    }

    private void listBoxFonts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBoxStyle.Items.Clear();
        string fontName = listBoxFonts.SelectedItem as string;

        if (FontCollection.ContainsKey(fontName))
        {
            foreach (var font in FontCollection[fontName])
            {
                if (!listBoxStyle.Items.Contains(font.Weight))
                    listBoxStyle.Items.Add(font.Weight);
            }
        }

        int index = listBoxStyle.FindStringExact("Normal");
        if (index == -1) { listBoxStyle.SelectedIndex = 0; }
        else { listBoxStyle.SelectedIndex = index; }

    }
}


public enum FontCharSet : byte
{
    ANSI_CHARSET = 0,
    DEFAULT_CHARSET = 1,
    SYMBOL_CHARSET = 2,
    SHIFTJIS_CHARSET = 128,
    HANGEUL_CHARSET = 129,
    HANGUL_CHARSET = 129,
    GB2312_CHARSET = 134,
    CHINESEBIG5_CHARSET = 136,
    OEM_CHARSET = 255,
    JOHAB_CHARSET = 130,
    HEBREW_CHARSET = 177,
    ARABIC_CHARSET = 178,
    GREEK_CHARSET = 161,
    TURKISH_CHARSET = 162,
    VIETNAMESE_CHARSET = 163,
    THAI_CHARSET = 222,
    EASTEUROPE_CHARSET = 238,
    RUSSIAN_CHARSET = 204,
    MAC_CHARSET = 77,
    BALTIC_CHARSET = 186,
}
public enum FontPrecision : byte
{
    OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS = 0,
    OUT_STRING_PRECIS = 1,
    OUT_CHARACTER_PRECIS = 2,
    OUT_STROKE_PRECIS = 3,
    OUT_TT_PRECIS = 4,
    OUT_DEVICE_PRECIS = 5,
    OUT_RASTER_PRECIS = 6,
    OUT_TT_ONLY_PRECIS = 7,
    OUT_OUTLINE_PRECIS = 8,
    OUT_SCREEN_OUTLINE_PRECIS = 9,
    OUT_PS_ONLY_PRECIS = 10,
}
public enum FontClipPrecision : byte
{
    CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS = 0,
    CLIP_CHARACTER_PRECIS = 1,
    CLIP_STROKE_PRECIS = 2,
    CLIP_MASK = 0xf,
    CLIP_LH_ANGLES = (1 << 4),
    CLIP_TT_ALWAYS = (2 << 4),
    CLIP_DFA_DISABLE = (4 << 4),
    CLIP_EMBEDDED = (8 << 4),
}
public enum FontQuality : byte
{
    DEFAULT_QUALITY = 0,
    DRAFT_QUALITY = 1,
    PROOF_QUALITY = 2,
    NONANTIALIASED_QUALITY = 3,
    ANTIALIASED_QUALITY = 4,
    CLEARTYPE_QUALITY = 5,
    CLEARTYPE_NATURAL_QUALITY = 6,
}
[Flags]
public enum FontPitchAndFamily : byte
{
    DEFAULT_PITCH = 0,
    FIXED_PITCH = 1,
    VARIABLE_PITCH = 2,
    FF_DONTCARE = (0 << 4),
    FF_ROMAN = (1 << 4),
    FF_SWISS = (2 << 4),
    FF_MODERN = (3 << 4),
    FF_SCRIPT = (4 << 4),
    FF_DECORATIVE = (5 << 4),
}

// if we specify CharSet.Auto instead of CharSet.Ansi, then the string will be unreadable
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public class LOGFONT
{
    public int lfHeight;
    public int lfWidth;
    public int lfEscapement;
    public int lfOrientation;
    public FontWeight lfWeight;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public bool lfItalic;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public bool lfUnderline;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public bool lfStrikeOut;
    public FontCharSet lfCharSet;
    public FontPrecision lfOutPrecision;
    public FontClipPrecision lfClipPrecision;
    public FontQuality lfQuality;
    public FontPitchAndFamily lfPitchAndFamily;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string lfFaceName;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("LOGFONT\n");
        sb.AppendFormat("   lfHeight: {0}\n", lfHeight);
        sb.AppendFormat("   lfWidth: {0}\n", lfWidth);
        sb.AppendFormat("   lfEscapement: {0}\n", lfEscapement);
        sb.AppendFormat("   lfOrientation: {0}\n", lfOrientation);
        sb.AppendFormat("   lfWeight: {0}\n", lfWeight);
        sb.AppendFormat("   lfItalic: {0}\n", lfItalic);
        sb.AppendFormat("   lfUnderline: {0}\n", lfUnderline);
        sb.AppendFormat("   lfStrikeOut: {0}\n", lfStrikeOut);
        sb.AppendFormat("   lfCharSet: {0}\n", lfCharSet);
        sb.AppendFormat("   lfOutPrecision: {0}\n", lfOutPrecision);
        sb.AppendFormat("   lfClipPrecision: {0}\n", lfClipPrecision);
        sb.AppendFormat("   lfQuality: {0}\n", lfQuality);
        sb.AppendFormat("   lfPitchAndFamily: {0}\n", lfPitchAndFamily);
        sb.AppendFormat("   lfFaceName: {0}\n", lfFaceName);

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Edit: Fixed some bugs with the code.